# Azure AD Sync, duplicate user

Tags: entra-id

*edit, Azure has emailed me and has suggested I follow steps found at [Identity synchronization and duplicate attribute resiliency](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsyncservice-duplicate-attribute-resiliency)*

I ran IDFIX, but I missed a row (one account had an incorrect UPN)

So, now after my sync I see

[image: csmith is in twice, once for Windows Server AD and again for Azure AD]

As you can see, C Smith is in twice.

I guess I need to delete him from Azure AD even though he is marked as a Windows Server AD, I suspect that if I can delete him and sync again it will add the correct details to Azure AD to mark it as a Windows Server AD account.

I have since corrected the UPN issue, but I still see separate accounts plus I get a duplicate sync error emailed to me.

*btw, I used the browser DEV tools to edit the name before I took the screenshot, I don't own mycorp.co.uk :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix, I did the following.

1. Disable DirSync

   ```
   Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled $false
   ```
2. Delete user with (The bogus Windows Server AD one)

   ```
   Remove-MsolUser
   ```
3. Enable DirSync

   ```
   Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled $true
   ```
4. Delete from Recycle bin with

   ```
   Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <user> -RemoveFromRecycleBin
   ```
5. Find the users ObjectID

   ```
   ldifde -d "CN=Christian Smith,CN=Users,DC=tndev,DC=local" -f C:\user.txt
   ```
6. Find `objectGUID::` in `c:\user.txt`
7. Update AzureID, setting the object ID to sync with to

   ```
   Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <upn> -ImmutableId <objectGUID>
   ```
8. Now, sync with

   ```
   Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
   ```